# IF EXISTS Statement in a PLSQL Procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql, user-defined-types

im very new at plsql and try to implement my procedure.

My procedure signature looks like

```
PROCEDURE signal_merge(s1 IN SIGNAL_STRUCT, s2 IN SIGNAL_STRUCT, rs OUT SIGNAL_STRUCT)
```

SIGNAL_STRUCT has an (I call it field?) "updated" that is of a type UPDATED_STRUCT

Now I want to do something like

```
if s2.updated exists
   do something
```

Even with Google I cant find a solution, can somebody explain me how I can achieve this?

Thank you all

Comment: What do you mean by 'exists'? The structure that's passed in will always have that field; so are you trying to find out something about its contents? Maybe just whether it is null or not null? Or are you trying to look at a field within that nested object type?

Comment: Exactly, I need to know its null or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need to know its null or not

Then test for that:

```
if s2.updated is not null then
  -- do something
end if;
```

[Read more](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/adobj/Sql-object-types-and-references.html#GUID-821233F6-ABA9-4100-B5E4-937F7DC57102).

Answer (score 3):

You want to know whether s2.updated is filled:

```
IF s2.updated IS NOT NULL THEN
  do something
END IF;
```

I would rather use a non-nullable boolean variable, however, that would either be true or false. Then you'd ask

```
IF s2.updated THEN
  do something
END IF;
```

which I consider more readable.

The struct declaration would then look like

```
TYPE signal_struct IS RECORD 
( 
  updated BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
  ...
);
```